# Freezing Peanut Butter Balls

Tags: freezing, peanut-butter

Something I have been making recently is brownie cupcakes (much the same as the molten cakes without the fudge). Using a standard box of dark chocolate brownies, I pour the ingredients, post-whisk, in a cupcake pan.

#### I came up with an idea to have frozen peanut butter balls inside of these cakes.

The typical peanut butter ball calls for peanut butter, sugar, and butter then refrigeration.

---

*Now the issue arises:* Would freezing the peanut butter and allowing it to melt in the oven, while the cupcakes cook, cause any issues (peanut butter through the bottom)?

This is part 2 of a question asked [previously](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/76062/best-practice-at-cutting-butter-and-sugar-in-peanut-butter-balls).

Comment: If you can't get this to work, stores around here used to carry 'peanut butter chips' which were the shape of chocolate chips, but made from peanut butter.  I haven't seen them in a while though.  Looking online shows a few, but the top hit is for Reeces brand, which is a blend of chocolate chips & peanut better chips

Answer (score 3):

The cold temperature of the peanut butter will completely change the cooking process of the brownie, as it will be cooled from the inside while heated from the outside. I don't think this is a good thing. You could try room temperature peanut butter, but PB has a [melting point around 150F](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070809194504AA6zSRI) (depending on the emulsifiers), and would probably melt before your brownie was fully cooked.

Unfortunately I do not think this will work.

Comment: My thought, too ... the cold peanut butter would keep the brownie batter nearby from cooking ... but as it's in cupcakes, you don't have to worry about slicing it, so it might come up like a chocolate lava cake w/ a chocolate & peanut butter center.  You just need it to hold together 'til the outside sets.  This might be one of those 'try it and see what happens' situations.